# What was the extent of Howard Stark's involvement in the Manhattan Project?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics

In *Iron Man* (2008), Tony Stark says that his father, Howard, worked on the Manhattan Project.

> TONY STARK: My old man had a philosophy: "Peace means having a bigger stick than the other guy."
>
> CHRISTINE EVERHART: That's a great line coming from the guy selling the sticks.
>
> TONY STARK: **My father helped defeat the Nazis. He worked on the Manhattan Project.** A lot of people, including your professors at Brown, would call that being a hero.
>
> <sub>*Iron Man* (2008)</sub>

If I'm not mistaken, the Manhattan Project was the atomic bomb. What was the extent of Howard Stark's involvement with the production of the atomic bomb during the Manhattan Project? I'm looking for an MCU or comics answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be much official info out there on this subject.

---

### In the MCU:

The *Guidebook to the Marvel Cinematic Universe* simply states that Stark helped create the first atomic bomb.

> **A WWII-era genius who helped create the first atomic bomb,** Howard Stark founded both Stark industries, a prominent munitions company, and S.H.I.E.L.D., an extra-governmental spy organization.
>
> <sub>*[Guidebook to the Marvel Cinematic Universe - Iron Man #2](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Guidebook_to_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_-_Iron_Man_2)*</sub>

[image]

---

### In the comics:

In *Captain America Annual Vol. 1 #9*, the Red Skull states that Stark was a major contractor on the American atomic weapon.

> RED SKULL: Well, Herr Stark, surely you can't hope to defy the Red Skull! **You are a major contractor on the American atomic weapon, ja?!**
>
> <sub>*[Captain America Annual Vol. 1 #9](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Annual_Vol_1_9)* (September, 1990)</sub>

[image]

---

I couldn't find anything that goes into any more detail than that.