# Has Eternal's Phastos given the Starks some of his technopathy ideas for Iron Man's hand gesture interface?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, eternals-2021

In the *Eternals* movie, we see Phastos performing hand gestures to actual technology-creation. While this is not the same hand gesture technology-creation of Tony Stark, since Stark relies on a machine, and Phastos relies on matter manipulation, they are quite similar.

[image]

[image]

Do we have any hints that Phastos has provided the Starks with alien technology, or perhaps just ideas?

Comment: Which "Starks" are you referring to?

Comment: Father and son, of course, since the Eternals where around for so many time, and providing key technology for key humans, I guess Howard Stark could have been a fine target.

Comment: There's really no indication that Howard or Tony had any contact with any Eternal.

Comment: But the graphics and hand gestures do seem pretty alike, don't they?

Comment: I'd agree... For me it was always implied in the movie that Phastos did not necessarily show or tell humankind about the inventions they could / should make but somehow "implant" the ideas about things to do / try next in their heads without directly telling them... in that case it would be totally plausible for him to plant the idea of this interface into Tony Stark... unfortunately I do not have anything to back this up... therefor only a comment.

Comment: @Arc - They look similar, sure, but [the same sort of technology also exists in _The Amazing Spider-Man_ films](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm-_BZrtZxk), and no one in that universe has been shown to use tech as advanced as Tony's. Given how gifted Tony is, it really doesn't seem like the type of thing he'd need help to create. It's far from being the most impressive technology he uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems very unlikely that Phastos would've directly assisted Tony with the development of holographic tech, or any other tech, since Phastos was said to have given up on humanity after the US military nuked Hiroshima and Nagasaki in 1945.

> SERSI: Please, Druig. You can’t stay here anymore. These Deviants are trying to keep us from killing their own kind. They have a conscience now. That makes them more dangerous.
>
> DRUIG: No, Sersi. That makes them us. Eternals and Deviants. Arishem’s children. But you are asking me to take control of a mind of a Celestial. I do not have that kind of power.
>
> SERSI: **We’ll need Phastos.**
>
> DRUIG: **Well, good luck. He gave up on humans a long time ago.**
>
> (Flashback to Hiroshima in August 1945, shortly after the city was nuked.)
>
> PHASTOS: **I did this. If my technology hadn’t helped them advance... Druig was right. Our mission was a mistake. These people... they’re not worth saving.**
>
> AJAK: Oh, Phastos.
>
> PHASTOS: They’re not worth saving.
>
> <sub>[*Eternals (2021)* - transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/eternals-2021-transcript/)</sub>

When we catch up to Phastos in 2023, he seems to have regained some faith in humanity based on his interactions with his husband and son, but he's apparently focused on tending to their needs, rather than helping the human race in general advance its tech.

> PHASTOS: So, after all these years, even you fell for Ajak’s lies.
>
> IKARIS: No need to rub it in.
>
> PHASTOS: Mm. It all makes sense why she wouldn’t let us interfere with human conflicts. Conflicts lead to war, and war actually leads to advancement in lifesaving technology and medicine. So our mission was never to make a peaceful or harmonious world, but to increase the population at all costs. Just farming humans as food for the Celestials, right?
>
> IKARIS: That’s bleak.
>
> PHASTOS: Well, so is telling your husband and your child that they could be dead within a few days.
>
> IKARIS: **Thought you’d given up on humans.**
>
> PHASTOS: **I got lucky. Okay? I have a family now. They give me faith again. And I see the good in humanity in them every single day. So, look, I cannot help you. I am never leaving them.**
>
> SERSI: Phastos...
>
> PHASTOS: **I’m sorry, Sersi. It was wrong for me to use my powers without thinking about the consequences in the first place. So, now, I choose to use my hands to fix my child’s bicycle, okay?**
>
> <sub>*Eternals (2021)* - transcript</sub>

It is more plausible that Phastos could've worked with *Howard* Stark at some point, especially in the development of the first atomic bomb. [Howard was certainly involved with that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/257037/what-was-the-extent-of-howard-starks-involvement-in-the-manhattan-project).

However, he was never shown to use holographic projections in any of his appearances, and while it's possible that he could've developed such technology off-screen -- and that Phastos could've assisted him with that -- it certainly hasn't been actively hinted at in any of the movies.

With the exception of Thanos, the Eternals were never referenced in any MCU film prior to *Eternals (2021)*, and the present-day portions of the film were set after the deaths of both Howard and Tony, neither of whom appeared (or were referenced) in any of the flashbacks.

Comment: I upvoted because of lots of good info in your answer, but I'm not yet fully convinced. You concede both Phastos and Howard had a lead role in the Manhattan project, and albeit Phastos abandoned his task of helping humankind after Hiroshima, he might as well have passed lots of knowledge to Howard during the development of the bomb? No mention to it on the MCU doesn't exclude it from ever having happened, right?

Comment: Also, that spiderman (*The Amazing Spider-man*) is from a different Earth (universe), correct?

Comment: @Arc - I acknowledge that Howard worked on the Manhattan Project, because it's clearly stated that he did. I don't acknowledge that Phastos did, as that isn't clearly confirmed anywhere. He obviously feels some degree of _culpability_ for what happened in Hiroshima, but we don't know exactly what he did that'd make him feel partly or wholly responsible for that event.

Comment: @Arc - In regard to the MCU not strictly precluding the possibility that Howard and Phastos worked together on something, can you clarify the precise nature of your question here? Were you asking whether there any are any _hints_ that Phastos worked directly with either Howard or Tony on "hand gesture interface" technology? Whether there are any _hints_ that Phastos worked directly with either Howard or Tony on any technology at all? Whether it's merely _possible_ that he worked with one or both of those men on something? None of the above?

Comment: @Arc - If you mean the Spider-Man from the _The Amazing Spider-Man_ films, yes, he's from a different universe. But the point I was making with [that comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259946/has-eternals-phastos-given-the-starks-some-of-his-technopathy-ideas-for-iron-ma/259954#comment715605_259946) is that holographic interface technology isn't especially advanced when to compared to other things Tony has invented.

Comment: Well, what I was hoping for was info from some other sources (like cartoons, scripts, or whatsoever), I agree that we are on the field of speculation right now. But to me, really, Phastos - at least on the movie - had not the power to influence minds, so I think he had to participate physically in giving humans technology. That's why I think he dresses like a 1940's physicist in the Hiroshima event. It's feasible to me that they've met and Strak was someone's worth to put effort on, but again just speculation. The question was written due to the visual resemblance between techonologies.

Comment: @Arc - I've looked for a screenplay for _Eternals (2021)_, but have found only a transcript. And the MCU version made his debut in that film, so there wouldn't be any references to him in anything released before that. The only MCU work released since then is _Spider-Man: No Way Home_, which he wasn't referenced in either, so for now, all we have is the Eternals film itself.

Comment: Based on what we see of Phastos in _Eternals (2021)_, I doubt he would've been involved in the Manhattan Project itself. Why he would he knowingly help build an atomic bomb, if he was totally opposed to it being used? It seems more likely that some _earlier_ contribution/s he made to the advancement of human knowledge helped pave the way for the Manhattan Project, making him indirectly rather than directly responsible.

Comment: Well, thanks for the digging anyways, I guess that is the best we can get for now. I agree with your answer.